# Magento 2 PWA setup with Adobe guidance but product images not shown

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-1.7, database

Refer this
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/tutorials/

Run Below command
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

only shown accessories category images and home page images.

if any has an idea then share it here.

Answer (score 0):

This explains the same issue you are facing please check this link:

https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/magento-2-product-images-not-showing-in-pwa-setup/

Comment: I have checked given by your suggestion  but still not working product images caches not generated .